# Cannot run the closure-linter task because of the "The system cannot find the path" error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-closure-linter

When I run this task in my `Gruntfile.js` I have the error: `The system cannot find the path specified`.

```
closureLint: {
    app:{
        closureLinterPath: '/3rdParty/closure_linter',
        command: 'gjslint',
        src: ['src/scripts/**'],
        options: {
            stdout: true,
            strict: true
      }
    }
}
```

I have the `3rdParty` folder with the `closure_linter` folder. `closure_linter` contains `*.py` files.

I'm using Windows 8 if this is important.

Comment: Did you try "3rdParty/closure_linter" ?

Comment: @MarioAraque yes, in this case I have the error `'3rdParty' is not recognized as an internal or external command`